# Want to know how custom type of quick sort is working

Tags: python, quicksort

Just for playing with quick sort, I just wrote a custom version of quick sort, and the code id below:

```
$ cat quick_sort_n.py
import random

num_iters = 0
def quick_sort(lst):
    global num_iters

    num_iters += 1

    all_inc = True

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            all_inc = False
            break

    if all_inc:
        return lst

    inc = dec = fin = []

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] < lst[i+1]:
            inc.append(lst[i])
    
    fin.append(lst[-1])

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            dec.append(lst[i])

    return quick_sort(inc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = []
    for i in range(100):
        r = random.randint(0, 100)
        if r not in lst:
            lst.append(r)
        
    print(lst)
    print(len(lst))
    result = quick_sort(lst)
    print(num_iters)
    print(result)
    print(len(result))
```

Below are the outputs of 3 runs:

```
$ python3 quick_sort_n.py 
[61, 15, 36, 18, 83, 16, 95, 92, 38, 59, 84, 87, 57, 45, 23, 6, 19, 91, 79, 70, 66, 26, 47, 69, 10, 20, 44, 33, 97, 8, 65, 40, 85, 21, 75, 81, 53, 4, 9, 7, 49, 60, 42, 31, 48, 41, 94, 100, 67, 55, 5, 34, 37, 24, 68, 43, 14, 29, 52, 96, 98, 77, 99, 86, 46, 80, 50, 93]
68
333
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 26, 29, 31, 33, 34, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 57, 59, 60, 61, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 75, 77, 79, 80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
68
$ python3 quick_sort_n.py 
[37, 92, 19, 41, 79, 50, 81, 93, 61, 32, 30, 22, 33, 16, 89, 68, 38, 25, 77, 76, 49, 18, 67, 31, 88, 6, 86, 83, 5, 65, 82, 87, 91, 75, 80, 9, 17, 69, 34, 78, 20, 53, 35, 46, 63, 0, 39, 11, 7, 47, 44, 1, 55, 74, 95, 98, 15, 48, 52, 2, 62]
61
244
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 61, 62, 63, 65, 67, 68, 69, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 98]
61
$ python3 quick_sort_n.py 
[36, 6, 99, 96, 85, 5, 82, 33, 39, 66, 64, 71, 13, 88, 7, 91, 55, 67, 62, 21, 60, 31, 24, 92, 80, 43, 11, 52, 46, 73, 54, 89, 59, 84, 0, 90, 30, 77, 70, 12, 34, 10, 94, 23, 27, 86, 63, 87, 51, 4, 65, 93, 58, 28, 42, 76, 72, 3, 2, 20, 19, 75, 18, 79, 22, 61, 16, 29]
68
280
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 36, 39, 42, 43, 46, 51, 52, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 99]
68
$
```

I wanted to know how this script is actually working. As far as I understand, every consecutive call to quick_sort() is taking only the inc list as input. Hence, the number of inputs is supposed to keep on reducing with every call. However, I see that the final list is of the same length (and sorted) as the initial list. This looks weird

The version of python on my machine is 3.8.0

The following modified code works (but it is very inefficient):

```
import random

num_iters = 0
def quick_sort(lst):
    global num_iters

    num_iters += 1

    increasing = True
    for x in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[x] > lst[x+1]:
            increasing = False
    if increasing:
        return lst

    inc = []
    dec = []
    equ = []

    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] < lst[i+1]:
            inc.append(lst[i])
    
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            dec.append(lst[i])
    
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i] == lst[i+1]:
            equ.append(lst[i])

    inc = [*inc, lst[len(lst)-1]]

    result = [*inc, *equ, *dec]

    return quick_sort(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = []
    for i in range(100):
        r = random.randint(0, 100)
        if r not in lst:
            lst.append(r)
        
    print(f"List: {lst}\nLength of original list: {len(lst)}")
    result = quick_sort(lst)
    print(f"Number of iterations: {num_iters}")
    print(f"Sorted list: {result}\nLength of sorted list: {len(result)}")
```

Comment: It is a sorting function, but it is not following the "quicksort" algorithm. Try following along by hand on a much smaller data set.

Comment: As @KennyOstrom said, try to take a smaller list of numbers and write by hand the steps that your function makes, then try to change the list a little bit until you can see a pattern(which is supposed to be like the quick sort alg) hopefully after that you'll have a better understanding of your function and how it works.

Comment: Sure. Will do as suggested and see if I get this working :)

Answer (score 2):

You're not reducing with every call. `inc`, `dec`, and `fin` all refer to the same list, since you initialized them with:

```
inc = dec = fin = []
```

So when you append to these lists, you're appending all the numbers to the same list. Then when you make the recursive call `quick_sort(inc)` you're calling with that full list.

To get 3 different lists you'd have to do

```
inc = []
dec = []
fin = []
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  Will try  setting the lists separately to [] initially and see how it works

Answer (score 2):

If I am right, this is a shaker sort. (Nothing to do with QuickSort, and certainly not a recommendable sorting algorithm.)

The mystery is due to the fact that, thanks to the Python semantics, `inc`, `dec` and `fin` are just aliases of the same array. As you can check, there are exactly `len(lst)` appends on every pass, hence no element is lost.